# Use dplyr's group_by to perform split-apply-combine

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, split-apply-combine

I am trying to use `dplyr` to do the following:

```
 tapply(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Species, shapiro.test)
```

I want to split the Petal.Lengths by Speicies, and apply a function, in this case `shapiro.test.` I read this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878678/understanding-difference-in-results-between-dplyr-group-by-vs-tapply) and quite a number of other pages. I am sort of able to split the variable into groups, using `do`:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  select(Petal.Length) %>%
  do(print(.$Petal.Length)) 

 [1] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.6 1.4 1.1 1.2
[16] 1.5 1.3 1.4 1.7 1.5 1.7 1.5 1.0 1.7 1.9 1.6 1.6 1.5 1.4 1.6
[31] 1.6 1.5 1.5 1.4 1.5 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.3 1.3 1.3 1.6 1.9
[46] 1.4 1.6 1.4 1.5 1.4
 [1] 4.7 4.5 4.9 4.0 4.6 4.5 4.7 3.3 4.6 3.9 3.5 4.2 4.0 4.7 3.6
[16] 4.4 4.5 4.1 4.5 3.9 4.8 4.0 4.9 4.7 4.3 4.4 4.8 5.0 4.5 3.5
[31] 3.8 3.7 3.9 5.1 4.5 4.5 4.7 4.4 4.1 4.0 4.4 4.6 4.0 3.3 4.2
[46] 4.2 4.2 4.3 3.0 4.1
```

The 'splitting' of the column into groups seems to be working. But the way to pass the pieces to shapiro.test is still eluding me. I see that `group_by` is different from *split into*.

I tried lots of variations, including:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  select(Petal.Length) %>%
  summarise(shapiro.test)
```

and also

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  select(Petal.Length) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(shapiro.test))

 # Error: expecting a single value
```

How can I make `dplyr` run `shapiro.test()` thrice, once for the Petal.Lengths of each Species?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could see two ways to do it, depending on how you want to use the output.  You could pull out just the p-values from `shapiro.test` in `summarise`.  Alternatively you could use `do` and save the results of each test in a list.

```
library(dplyr)
```

With `summarise`, pulling out just the p-values:

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(stest = shapiro.test(Petal.Length)$p.value)

     Species      stest
1     setosa 0.05481147
2 versicolor 0.15847784
3  virginica 0.10977537
```

Using `do`:

```
tests = iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    do(test = shapiro.test(.$Petal.Length))

# Resulting list
tests$test

[[1]]

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  .$Petal.Length
W = 0.955, p-value = 0.05481


[[2]]

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  .$Petal.Length
W = 0.966, p-value = 0.1585


[[3]]

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  .$Petal.Length
W = 0.9622, p-value = 0.1098
```

Comment: Thanks @aosmith. Storing the results of summarize to a list is a neat trick.

Comment: so awesome, I shouted out loud when I was able to implement this, with slight tweaks to extract multiple statistics from a t.test:
`dfz %>% group_by(tooth,position) %>% summarise(tt.est=t.test(diff)$estimate,tt.pv=t.test(diff)$p.value)`

Comment: How to do this if  `iris` is really a MySQL table? I keep getting `Error in stopifnot(is.numeric(x)) : object '{column_name}' not found` errors.

Comment: @adib My best guess is that you might need backticks around the column name inside `summarise`.  That would be the case if your variable name wasn't syntactically valid, such as containing symbols like curly brackets.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `tidy()` function from the [broom package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=broom), to turn the output of `shapiro.test()` into a data.frame then you can use `do()`.

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  do(tidy(shapiro.test(.$Petal.Length)))
```

This gives you:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: Species [3]

Species statistic    p.value                      method
      <fctr>     <dbl>      <dbl>                      <fctr>
1     setosa 0.9549768 0.05481147 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
2 versicolor 0.9660044 0.15847784 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
3  virginica 0.9621864 0.10977537 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
```

This is adapted from my answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262007/using-dplyrs-do-with-summary/36263994#36263994).