# Nth smallest value for every column in data.frame in R

Tags: r, dcast

I want to find the nth smallest number for every column in a data.frame.

In the below example I specify actually the second smallest value using the dcast nth function. Can someone help with the coding of the function?

```
library(vegclust)
library(dplyr)
data(wetland)
dfnorm = decostand(wetland,"normalize")
dfchord = dist(dfnorm, method = "euclidean")
dfchord = data.frame(as.matrix(dfchord)
number_function = function(x) nth(x,2) # can change 2 to any number..

answer_vector = apply(dfchord, 2, number) # here, 2 specifying apply on columns
```

The actual answer would be something like this..

```
ans = c(0.5689322,0.579568297,0.315017693,0.315017693,0.632246369, 0.868563003, 0.704638684, 0.35827587, 0.725220337, 0.516397779) # length of 1:38
```

Comment: It sounds like a bit of a strange thing to do. To make this more readable for yourself and your colleagues in the future, you might want to [melt](http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html) and then [split-apply-combine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664644/use-dplyrs-group-by-to-perform-split-apply-combine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my example;

```
num_func <- function(x, n) nth(sort(x), n)
sapply(dfchord, num_func, n = 2)  # edited (thanks for @thelatemail's comment)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a warning, if you don't specify the order for dplyr's `nth()`, it will not actually do the sorting:

For example,

```
> sapply(mtcars, dplyr::nth, 2)
    mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear    carb 
 21.000   6.000 160.000 110.000   3.900   2.875  17.020   0.000   1.000   4.000   4.000
```

which is actually just the second row of the data:

```
> mtcars[2,]
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
```

The `nth` function in Rfast does sort by default:

```
> sapply(mtcars, Rfast::nth, 2)
   mpg    cyl   disp     hp   drat     wt   qsec     vs     am   gear   carb 
10.400  4.000 75.700 62.000  2.760  1.615 14.600  0.000  0.000  3.000  1.000
```

If you are sensitive to performance, the Rfast version was written to scale well by using a partial sort, which isn't true for solutions based on `sort`, `order` or `rank` (including `dplyr::nth`).

Comment: Rfast has a function colnth, which is even faster than using sapply and nth, but it requires that you specify for each column the nth value that you wish to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already like `dplyr` here is what I do now days with `purrr`:

```
purrr::map_dbl(mtcars, ~nth(., 2, order_by = .))
   mpg    cyl   disp     hp   drat     wt   qsec     vs     am   gear   carb 
10.400  4.000 75.700 62.000  2.760  1.615 14.600  0.000  0.000  3.000  1.000
```

or with just `dplyr` since its already loaded for `nth()`:

```
summarise_all(mtcars, funs(nth(., 2, order_by = .))
   mpg cyl disp hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
1 10.4   4 75.7 62 2.76 1.615 14.6  0  0    3    1
```

Comment: Without packages - `mtcars[sapply(mtcars, rank, ties.method="first")==2]`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a faster alternative to `nth` and `sort`, there is the `topn` function in the package "kit" in CRAN. Please look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So here it is an answer to get any nth value across the columns of any data.frame you need only change the x in the y[x].

```
x = dfchord

for (i in (1:ncol(x))) {
  y = sort(x[,i], decreasing=FALSE)
  ans$small[i] = y[2] # this is the second biggest number, replace the value with whatever you want
  ans$rel = rownames(x)
}

answer = data.frame( 'nth' = ans$small, 'rel' = ans$rel)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr::summarize_each`

```
n <- 2
dfchord %>% summarize_each(funs(nth(sort(.),n)))
#          X5        X8       X13        X4       X17       X3        X9       X21       X16       X14        X2       X15        X1        X7
# 1 0.5689322 0.5795683 0.3150177 0.3150177 0.6322464 0.868563 0.7046387 0.3582759 0.7252203 0.5163978 0.3651484 0.5163978 0.3582759 0.4222794
#         X10      X40       X23       X25       X22      X20        X6      X18      X12       X39       X19       X11       X30       X34
# 1 0.4222794 0.507107 0.6206017 0.4536844 0.4536844 0.654303 0.5126421 0.338204 0.338204 0.5126421 0.5393651 0.5804794 0.7270723 0.5242481
#        X28       X31       X26       X29       X33       X24       X36      X37       X41       X27       X32       X35       X38
# 1 0.735765 0.5242481 0.7270723 0.8749704 0.5715592 0.4933355 0.4933355 0.574123 0.7443697 0.6333863 0.6333863 0.7296583 0.6709442
```